# auto deletion of documents in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, database, nosql

I have just started to use Mongodb. Got stuck.

So I have a collection with fields:

> _id
>   startDate  (long)
>   endDate  (long)
>   name

Now I want to auto-delete documents which are older than specific date.
I created a TTL index for `startDate` field, set the expiration time after 2 mins and tested if it expires. While inserting a document with `startDate` as `isoDate` it worked and expired.

```
..insert({startDate:newDate()})--> Got deleted after 2 secs.
```

My question is whatever data were previously installed have startDate as long value. So how will that work?

Answer (score 0):

TTL indexes only work on `isoDate`s. Run an update to convert your longs to isoDates, or just remove them manually (presumably, everything that is a long will be older than your cutoff anyway, or will be soon).

Comment: Thanks Paul! Seems like I have to delete documents based upon their creation Date not the startDate value. I don't have creationDate as a separate field as well. I understand I can get Timestamp of ObjectId if I want to get the date of document created. But the documentation mentions we cannot create TTL indexes on _id. Am I right? Any suggestion?

Comment: If you don't have such a field, add it! Update your docs to add a create_date field using the timestamp from the ObjectId (I've never used this function, but it makes sense), then TTL Index on the create_date.